# Installation of tflite-model-maker on mac fails

Tags: python

I'm completely new on Python, so using PyCharm 2022.1 I'm trying to install tflite-model-maker on mac but always fail. Returned errors are:

```
An error occurred while building with CMake.
        Command:
          cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
        Install target:
          install
        Source directory:
          /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f
        Working directory:
          /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build
      Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python-headless
Failed to build opencv-python-headless
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python-headless, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

And earlier in the whole terminal report:

```
 In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_numpy.cpp:6:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_numpy.hpp:4:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.hpp:36:
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:242:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_SIZE'
          if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(value) != 3) {
              ^
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:245:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_ITEM'
          title = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(value, 2);
                  ^
      2 errors generated.
      [1091/1100] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2_highgui.cpp.o
      FAILED: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2_highgui.cpp.o

...

In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_highgui.cpp:1:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_highgui.hpp:4:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.hpp:36:
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:242:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_SIZE'
          if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(value) != 3) {
              ^
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:245:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_ITEM'
          title = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(value, 2);
                  ^
      2 errors generated.
      [1092/1100] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2_util.cpp.o
      FAILED: modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2_util.cpp.o

...

In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_util.cpp:1:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2_util.hpp:4:
      In file included from /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-install-_60a3wey/opencv-python-headless_f3f9ce9981dd47e2bd8cf7f7b304f20f/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.hpp:36:
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:242:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_SIZE'
          if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(value) != 3) {
              ^
      /private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:245:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_ITEM'
          title = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(value, 2);
                  ^
      2 errors generated.
      [1093/1100] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/backends/fluid/gfluidcore_func.avx2.cpp.o
      [1094/1100] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/backends/common/serialization.cpp.o
      [1095/1100] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/backends/fluid/gfluidimgproc_func.avx2.cpp.o
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
        File "/private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
          cmkr.make(make_args, install_target=cmake_install_target, env=env)
        File "/private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 660, in make
          self.make_impl(clargs=clargs, config=config, source_dir=source_dir, install_target=install_target, env=env)
        File "/private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 699, in make_impl
```

And the directory "/private/var/folders/wc/kmpkxd0x57v762v9j6_xcswh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pt4hwpl8" doesn't exists.

As far as I can understand, errors are found, the process is stopped and the created files and folders are deleted, so at the last command cmake can't find any source folder.
The question is obviously why are those errors (use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_SIZE', use of undeclared identifier 'PyTuple_GET_ITEM') found. Is it a matter of package versions?  I use python 3.7 and followed information stored in TF requirement page...

Or maybe I'm missing a general option somewhere?

Also tried to install directly opencv-python-headless but identical result.

I use PyCharm 2022.1.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're getting this error because of your pip's version. Your pip version should be greater than 20.3. You can check your pip version using this command:

```
pip -V
```

Then run this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

And install opencv-python.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If these two commands solve your problem you don't have to execute the commands below.

And tflite-model-maker also needs `sndfile`. On Mac, you can download this package using this command:

```
brew install libsndfile
```

After running these commands, you can try to install tflite-model-maker. Use this command:

```
pip install tflite-model-maker
```

If this command raise an error, try to install nightly version of tflite-model-maker:

```
pip install tflite-model-maker-nightly
```

Comment: It didn't work. Same failure

Comment: Try another compiler. Looks like you're getting error because of your IDE.